# Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.(AngularFireList)

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I tried to retrieve data from firebase database as [this tutorial](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/managing-firebase-user-relationships-to-database-records/)
but I get this error;

```
Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.(AngularFireList)
```

I want to retrieve specific data for the current user (when user login to the app)

can anyone help me to solve this problem

this html page

```
<ion-content padding>
  <!--  مسسوول عن عرض البيانات  -->
  <ul *ngFor ="let d of datanote " class="collection" class="colorul" text-right >
    <li class= "collection-item" >
      <ion-card class="backgounddiv" >     
        <ion-card-header>
          <strong class="colorli" >{{d.title}}<br></strong>
        </ion-card-header>
        <ion-card-content>
          <strong class="colorli" >{{d.desciption}}</strong>
        </ion-card-content>   
      </ion-card>
    </li>
  </ul>
</ion-content>
```

this ts page

```
export class HomePage {
  datanote :AngularFireList<users[]> ;
  userId: string;

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    private ev: Events,
    public firestoreService:FierbaceserverProvider,
    public navParams: NavParams, 
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private db: AngularFireDatabase 
  ) {  }

  ngOnInit():AngularFireList <users[]> {
    if (this.userId) return;

    this.datanote=this.db.list(`note-list/${this.userId}`);

    return this.datanote; 
  }
}
```

Comment: If you do, `console.log(this.datanote)` what do you see? Object? Array? Also `ngOnInit()` returns `void` see [angular doc](https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit)

Comment: If you do, console.log(this.datanote) ?nothing

Answer (score 0):

`this.datanote` is a reference at the moment, it doesn't contain the database values, in order to get these values you need to wait for the observable.

```
private noteList$: Subscription;

ngOnInit() {
  if (this.userId) return;

  this.noteList$ = this.db.list(`note-list/${this.userId}`)
    .snapshotChanges()
    .subscribe(snapshot => {
      this.datanote = snapshot;
    });
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  noteList$.unsubscribe();
}
```

You should then update your HTML to check if `this.datanote` exists with an `ngIf="datanote"` on the `ion-content`.

```
<ion-content *ngIf="datanote" padding>
  <!--  مسسوول عن عرض البيانات  -->
  <ul *ngFor ="let d of datanote " class="collection" class="colorul" text-right >
    <li class= "collection-item" >
      <ion-card class="backgounddiv" >     
        <ion-card-header>
          <strong class="colorli" >{{d.title}}<br></strong>
        </ion-card-header>
        <ion-card-content>
          <strong class="colorli" >{{d.desciption}}</strong>
        </ion-card-content>   
      </ion-card>
    </li>
  </ul>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: I have a doubt. By adding the keyword async to ths callback fns, are you deferring its execution. Can you explain the usage here?tnx

Comment: Good pick up, I didn't mean to add `async`.

Comment: give me error in this line this.datanote = snapshot;

Comment: What is the error? I haven't tested the code, but the general idea should work.

Comment: the error (Type 'AngularFireAction<DatabaseSnapshot<{}>>[]' is not assignable to type 'AngularFireList<users[]>'.
  Property 'query' is missing in type 'AngularFireAction<DatabaseSnapshot<{}>>[]'.)

Comment: These are typing issues and can be fixed by setting the correct type.